# Raising alerts from backend javascript

Tags: javascript, android, meteor, client-server, ionic-framework

I'm building an app with Meteor and Meteoric (integration with Ionic, which replaces the angular with blaze). I have a method running on server which I want it to popup alert for the user if some condition is met, but of course I can't do so because Ionic is a client side framework.

I tried to return a variable to the place in client where I call the method and make it raise the popup but it just ignores it. (Maybe because I can't really do it between client and server?)

Anyone has a suggestion for this?

Comment: Please post your [code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a request from the client to the server, and depending on the response on the client you can alert (or continue if for example nothing went wrong). What did you try already? And what is the method doing?

Comment: I'm sending something an item to someone, and if he already got it I want it to raise the popup.

I tried to return '1' if he got it, so I could put this '1' in a variable on the client side and raise a popup, with no success.

Comment: Do you have some code which you can post of client/server? Then people can take a look at it to see what does not come through. Like how are you sending this item from server to client, http request? Sockets?